# CSS Class Names Affect Styles

Tags: css

Can I make a class's name which will affect styles in this class?

i.e.

```
.h-20px{
    height: 20px;
}
```

I want to add `-i` after class name which will automaticly affect height, `height: 20px !important;` like that:

```
.h-20px-i{
    height: 20px !important;
}
```

Is there any solution for this?